# Data analysis: Time series for Bacterial population data

Tags: time-series

Could anyone please help with data analysis. Briefly, I am studying how the population of a bacteria changes at different points (port 1 to port 10) within a biofilter over the course of 30 days(like a time series)

For example, if data looks like below,:

```
Samples:........Day 0............Day 15......Day 30


Port 1...........3.6..............4.5.........5.0

to
.

Port 10.........2.8...............2.9.........3.2
```

then how can I figure out whether there is a significant variation between the data sets (or as  whole) from day 30 to Day 0?

Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a mixed effects model (some also use the term hierarchical model) would be appropriate.

Comment: So, ports 1-10, each measured for 30 days? And you want to compare the ports to each other, or just how change happens for each port, irrespective of others?

Answer (score -1):

Sir,
  In medical sciences researchers have made standardized level of control group which is normal reporting in medical term. we may compare the bacterial count.
(1)Use compared t- test on per day data with mean differences and standard deviation (Pooled) or control group s.d.at significance levels(for example,5%)
(2) make  a frequency distribution of grouped data of 30 days three categories of above average, average, below average count of bacteria ,for example,0-10,10-20,20-30 if data  is like. Show in counts cross tabulation and apply chi-square test. regression analysis of time (day1 to 30th day) and score of bacterial counts per day.